# Forwarding changes from one HG repository to another

Tags: mercurial

I have recently cloned an HG repository into another one, since the project had to be slightly changed and i couldn't keep it with the other codebase.

Some changes though are common, and so needed to be updated in the older repository as well.

How can this be done?

I'd like to know more specifically:

1. Are changes that are not group together in a commit (sporadic changes i've made to code files) can be somehow grouped together and updated in the 1st repository (the one i cloned from).
2. If not, how can this be done if i make all changes grouped in the same commit?
3. Other recommendations for strategies for handling such cases will be great!

Thanks

Comment: Not to be mean in any way, but you really need to pick up some DVCS fundamentals before answers to those specific questions will help you.  You can very easily move changes from one repo to another and if you do it right bring across only those changes you want.  Give the first few chapters of the Mercurial book a read and after that check answers around SO for "vendor branch".

Comment: Pushing and/or pulling between the repositories is the answer.

Comment: pushing/pulling allows for sending across different CHANGESETS. what if the changes made are not contained in a specific changeset? or if some changeset contains changes not needed to be pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem are you seeing exactly? What have you tried?

Can you clarify the issue, it seems like you are just looking for a way to pull from another repo, in which case:

```
hg pull -r {RevisionYouWantFromOtherRepo} {pathToSecondRepository}
```

Comment: i know how to pull/push specific changesets. My question was -- what if a changeset contains some changes that i do not want to push? is there any way to overcome this, and "repackage" only the needed changes as a changeset to be pushed?

Comment: Short of manual patch hunks, you're screwed. This is why you need to commit early and commit often. It ensures each change is selectable as a bona fide changeset and all the other benefits of DVCS that that brings.